# Subtotaling an arraylist that was imported from a csv file

Tags: java, list, arraylist, subtotal

I'm making a school project for a java coding class and need some help

I've imported a CSV file with some information on it that has been separated into an ArrayList and wish to total each different category in the file.

right now my output is:

```
Item       |  Category |    Amount |     Price |  Location
Carrots    |      Food |        12 |        $2 |   Walmart
Potatoes   |      Food |        15 |        $3 |   Walmart
T-Shirt    |   Clothes |         1 |       $16 |   Walmart
Toothbrush |  Cleaning |         2 |        $2 |   Walmart
```

my goals are to get subtotals for each category such as:

```
Item       |  Category |    Amount |     Price |  Location
Carrots    |      Food |        12 |        $2 |   Walmart
Potatoes   |      Food |        15 |        $3 |   Walmart
                       Subtotal for Food is: $69
T-Shirt    |   Clothes |         1 |       $16 |   Walmart
                    Subtotal for Clothes is: $16
Toothbrush |  Cleaning |         2 |        $2 |   Walmart
                   Subtotal For Cleaning is: $4
```

and then to eventually have the whole thing totalled at the end and displayed like this:

```
Item       |  Category |    Amount |     Price |  Location
Carrots    |      Food |        12 |        $2 |   Walmart
Potatoes   |      Food |        15 |        $3 |   Walmart
                      Subtotal for Food is: $69
T-Shirt    |   Clothes |         1 |       $16 |   Walmart
                   Subtotal for Clothes is: $16
Toothbrush |  Cleaning |         2 |        $2 |   Walmart
                   Subtotal For Cleaning is: $4
                                   Total is: $89
```

Here is my code right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     ArrayList<output> csvstuff = new ArrayList<output>();

    String fileName = "Project2.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName); 

try {
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);

    while(inputStream.hasNext()) {
        String data = inputStream.next();
        String[] values= data.split(",");
        String Item = values[0];
        String Category = values[1];
        String Amount = values[2];
        String Price = values[3];
        String Location = values[4];

        String format = "%-10s |%10s |%10s |%10s |%10s\n";
        System.out.printf(format, values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]);


        output _output = new output(Item,Category,Amount,Price,Location);
        csvstuff.add(_output);
    }

    inputStream.close();

} 

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing values while reading in the loop, add it to arraylist as you have done. Then sort the data based on Category type. Refer to `comparable` and `comparator` in java.
And now you can simply iterate over the list and keep counting the subtotal for each category.

Useful link: [Comarator v/s Comparable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort all rows by their category.
2. Walk the sorted list and keep a subtotal count.
3. If an item is in a different category than the previous one, emit a subtotal row and clear the subtotal value. (You'll also have to do this once after the last row.)
4. *Then* emit a line describing the current row.

To emit a grand total, simply keep another total that is updated with each row and *never* cleared.

Comment: how would I sort each row by the category?

Comment: The usual method looks like this: `Collections.sort(people, (a, b) -> a.name.compareToIgnoreCase(b.name));` Adapt the identifiers to your example.